# NVIVO 12 - The Media File Format Not Recognized

Tags: windows, codec

I installed NVIVO 12 on a windows server 2019 machine and a Windows 7, and still get this error when I'm importing media files with .m4a, .mp3 (low and high quality), and .wav extensions. I wanted to code and annotate on audio files, does anyone know any way around it.

[image]

Comment: [Windows 10 Codec Pack](https://www.windows10codecpack.com/)

Comment: compatible with "Microsoft Windows 10, 8.1, 8, 7, Vista, XP, 2000, 2008, & 2003"

Answer (score 0):

Got this working after several tries. Here are the steps I took.

1. Downloaded the k-lite codec pack from [K-Lite](https://codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_mega.htm), click on server 1 or 2
2. Installed on Windows 7 and it worked, so installed on windows server 2019 but it wasn't working
3. Aparently Windows Audio Service was disabled on windows server. Enabled it by clicking on the audio icon on the task bar and clicked enable. It previously had a X underneath the icon.